# Get first node using E4X with mixed namespaces?

Tags: javascript, e4x

Consider an XML snippet with a handful of namespaces:

```
<meal xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <veg id="7" />
    <lunch id="123">
        <veg id="990" />
    </lunch>
    <dinner id="324">
         <veg id="111" />
    </dinner>
 </meal>
```

Using JavaScript E4X, how can you explicitly select the first `veg` node's id property?

It's important to **explicitly include all namespaces** as well. This is the reason for my `..*::` syntax below. I realize I'm using the wrong operator here.

I've tried this, which unfortunately gets ALL veg node id values:

```
var veg = meal..*::veg.@id.toString()
//currently gets 7990111
```

How can I get the value of `7`?

Comment: An XPath 1.0 expression will be `(//*[local-name()='veg])[1]/@id` and XPath 2.0 will be `(//*:veg)[1]/@id`. If your are not seeking for an XPath solution, please retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var veg = meal..*::veg[0].@id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
`var veg = meal..*::veg[position()=1].@id.toString()`

`veg[position()=1]` tells XPath you want the veg node at the first position.
I just complete your initial xpath expression.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the call to position. Is that E4X?

Comment: `position() = 1` is XPath, not E4X.

Answer (score 1):

```
var meal = // xml;
var veg = meal..*::veg.@id[0];
```

Comment: I hadn't refreshed my screen before posting, and I didn't realize this was more or less identical to Martin's response (save for the very minor difference that I'm creating a list of id's, and he's creating a list of veg nodes).It might be helpful to note, however, that the top level node (meal) of the XML does not need to be directly referenced. In my case, I created a variable with the same name as the top node, which I think adds to the readability.